# Basic Help: Reading Ruby Script Case Syntax

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

I've never done a thing with ruby script before, and was hoping someone here would have a quick answer.  I'm on a time sensitive project, and was hoping SO could provide some insight.

I've googled around here, and sought out some ruby script guides, and think I understand most of the following code, but there are a few things I wasn't able to figure out.

I have the following exceprt from a ruby script, and I just need to know what it's doing:

where docName and document_name are a string of a file path

```
case docName 
when /^QRX/ then document_name = "/TRPRR/#{docName}"
when /^BVN/ then document_name = "/TRPRR/#{docName}"
....
```

There are a bunch of other cases, and I understand case statements. I don't understand the following:

Is the **/^QRX/** some kind of regular expression or something? And what does the **#{docName}** do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the `/^QRX/`, etc. performs a regular expression match against `docName`, and if it matches, it performs the code following.

The `#{docName}` is how ruby handles string interpolation:

```
docName = "foo"
puts "/TRPRR/#{docName}" # Outputs "/TRPRR/foo"
```